# Speed-up large number of files deletion on NTFS volumes

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Mass deleting files in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/19762/mass-deleting-files-in-windows)
>   [How can I speed up the deleting of very large directories on XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/45661/how-can-i-speed-up-the-deleting-of-very-large-directories-on-xp)

Every now and then I need to delete a folder containing something like 500k files from an NTFS volume. I do this with Windows Explorer.

Since NTFS journals all the service data changes each deletion is carried out serially and so the whole 500k files deletion takes ages. I remember when I did the same in FAT32 it ran uncomparably faster.

Is there any way to speed up deletion of large number of files on NTFS volumes?

Comment: Check out the following Q&A's: http://superuser.com/questions/19762/mass-deleting-files-in-windows ; http://superuser.com/questions/74786/quickest-way-to-delete-big-folders-in-windows ; http://superuser.com/questions/45661/how-can-i-speed-up-the-deleting-of-very-large-directories-on-xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open "Command Prompt" (cmd.exe) and run the following command:

```
del /f /s /q foldername
```