# Copying and deleting time lengths different for same file size

Tags: windows

It took about 40 minutes to transfer a 90GB folder from my desktop to my external HDD. Why does it take over 3 hours to delete that same 90GB folder from my desktop? I understand that the file ops are different but I still don't see why one would take so much more time than the other to complete.

Comment: because your source HDD is fully. I think

Comment: Huh? My HDD has a 2TB capacity. It's nowhere near full.

Comment: Windows XP, Vista, W7, W8??

Comment: [Suggestions here](http://superuser.com/questions/76906/deleting-large-amount-of-files-in-windows-is-slow)

Answer (score 0):

Did you move to the recycle bin or use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> to completely delete it?

If there were a lot of files it can be slow to put them all in recycling.

Comment: I used Shift+Delete to 'permanently delete' them.