# Faster way to delete files on a network drive

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a network drive and I am trying to delete a large folder. Man what a pain!

It's been on the "Calculating" phase forever now (it's at 26GB).
Isn't there a way to just delete *boom*! I don't need to know how many files and how big they are!

I'm using Windows 7.
I am using "shift" delete to skip the recycle bin.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/19762/83235?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be able to use the command prompt. I might be off on some of the details of the procedure, but try this:

1. Open the Start Menu and in the text box, type `cmd.exe` and hit Enter (or open the command prompt using your preferred method)
2. Switch to the network drive by typing `Z:` (where `Z` is the letter of the network drive)
3. Change to the parent directory of the directory you're trying to delete using `cd path\to\parent\directory`
4. Delete the directory using `rmdir /S giantdir`

For example, if you want to delete the directory `O:\MG\WTF\BBQ\SOMANYFILES`:

```
C:\Documents And Settings\Me> O:

O:> cd MG\WTF\BBQ

O:\MG\WTF\BBQ> rmdir /S SOMANYFILES
```

Or now that I think about it, I think you could just do

```
C:\Documents And Settings\Me> O:

O:> rmdir /S MG\WTF\BBQ\SOMANYFILES
```

but you would miss out on the chance to see Windows spell out `OMGWTFBBQ` in terminal font ;-)

By the way, `rmdir` (or `del`) does not move things to the Recycle Bin, it just deletes them, so be careful not to delete things you don't really want to.

Comment: You don't need the +`.exe`, it will run just fine if you type `cmd` and hit enter.

Comment: I do `W:\>del backup-043010`, then it says `W:\backup-043010\*, Are you sure (Y/N)? Y`. After a fraction of second it says it's done, but the folder is still here!

Comment: try w:\rmdir backup-04310

Comment: @Corey: thanks, I'm more used to Linux so I forget about those details. @nute: OK, apparently `del` doesn't quite act the way it seems like it should, based on the help text. Try `rmdir` instead. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: is that really faster than through explorer?

Comment: I would think so... for one thing, it doesn't bother to count up the number of files it's deleting, or their total size. At least it's definitely not slower.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue. have 500G folder with tiny files to remove and window delete not work at all.
The best way I found is using ftp to connect to NAS and delete the file which I could delete about 100+ files/ sec.

Your NAS may or may not support ftp option. but if it does, you r in luck