# speeding up deleting thousands of files in windows explorer

Tags: windows, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mass deleting files in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/19762/mass-deleting-files-in-windows)

I know, using the command-line but often this is not possible, e.g deleting the result of a search in Windows Explorer or I'm just too lazy to start typing. Most of the time Windows is busy with gathering information about the selection you just made and want to delete. Is there a way to skip this step so that the deletion is right away? A registry setting perhaps?

Answer (score -2):

Are you trying to delete the temporary files generated due to browsing?
In that case `Piriform's CCleaner` will do the job