# Fastest way to delete a large folder

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mass deleting files in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/19762/mass-deleting-files-in-windows)

Windows 8 provides several ways to delete a folder, but some seem more efficient than others. For example, you can use Windows Explorer, which will enumerate every item in the folder before deleting them one by one. From the command line, there is `del` and `rmdir`.

When working with a folder with a deep hierarchy containing tens of thousands of files, what method for deletion is the fastest? No recycle binning desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186737/whats-the-fastest-way-to-delete-a-large-folder-in-windows it seems that:

> rmdir /s /q folder

is the fastest way.