# How to delete empty files with Hexadecimal names on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, cmd.exe, git-bash

I have a very vital folder that is being "infested" with unknown files. The 500,000+ files have HEXadecimal Names and most of them are 0 bytes each.
[This is how the files names look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XorTw.png)

```
:
08/28/2019  04:20 PM                 0 70F55530
08/28/2019  09:00 PM                 0 70F55630
08/28/2019  04:37 PM                 0 70F56530
08/28/2019  04:55 PM                 0 70F57530
08/28/2019  09:34 PM                 0 70F57630
08/28/2019  05:12 PM                 0 70F58530
08/28/2019  09:52 PM                 0 70F58630
:
```

I did a virus scan but found nothing. Incidentally, my original files are still in the folder.

I have tried deleting the strange files via git-bash:

`find . -type f -name "[0-9]*" -delete`

and also

`find . -type f ! -name "*.*" -delete`

but it takes so long.

I'm not sure of the regex to use and I don't want to delete my real files and folders. Is there a faster way of removing only those files with the hexadecimal names?

Comment: You don't seem adequately concerned about the source of these files.

Comment: are there other files in the folder that you need to keep? If not, how about a simple `del *.*`?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator which were created nearly 2 months ago...

Comment: I am very concerned @TwistyImpersonator - that's why I did a malware scan and also made restoration points. At first I thought it was ransomware but my original files are still in there..

Comment: The huge number of files makes it so hard to browse the folder. What I'm sure of is these files are only in that one folder...

Comment: All I need is a quick solution to delete the strange files @spikey_richie

Comment: Try `del ????????.` - this command will delete all files which have the name 1-8 chars long without the extension. Of course check that there is no such files which must NOT be deleted.

Comment: NTFS is slow. No way around that. // Related: https://superuser.com/q/19762/219095

Comment: I use this in your situation....https://emcosoftware.com/unlock-it

Comment: Use the Command Prompt and not git-bash.

Comment: Thanks @Akina. This takes sometime but at least it shows which files its removing

Comment: *at least it shows which files its removing* `dir ????????.` shows too, but it may be faster, especially with /B option. And its output may be saved into a file.

Comment: Thanks @Akina. I ran your first option for ~5 hours and they were still alot more left. I resorted to using git-bash for the remaining ~200,000 files and ```find . -type f -size 0b -delete``` ran for less than one hour. I'm so glad my files are still there even though I failed to understand the cause of the issue...